# Equipment suitable for squads/members of a mercenary company?

Tags: dnd-4e, equipment

What would be a good set of equipment for squads/members of a mercenary company inspired by modern special forces teams or the [Wraith Recon](http://www.mongoosepublishing.com/rpg/detail.php?qsID=1617&qsSeries=67) setting?

The requirements are that the squad could potentially operate on their own for a long time in "hostile" territory and would need to be able to navigate, circumvent obstacles and communicate well.

So far I've only looked at wonderous items (ignoring item rarity) and my current list includes:

#### Each member gets:

- [01] 3x Eternal Chalk (white, red, blue)<sup>[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3217)</sup>
- [01] 1x Woundstitch Powder<sup>[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=6198)</sup>
- [05] 2x Bag of Holding<sup>[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=550)</sup>
- [10] 1x Rope of Climbing<sup>[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=560)</sup>

#### Each squad gets:

- [02] 2x Silent Tool (crowbar, hammer)<sup>[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3255)</sup>
- [04] 1x Chime of Awakening<sup>[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3198)</sup>
- [04] 1x Everlasting Provisions<sup>[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=552)</sup>
- [05] 1x Instant Campsite<sup>[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3231)</sup>
- [07] 1x Map of Unseen Lands<sup>[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=6148)</sup>
- [09] 1x Map of Orienteering<sup>[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3238)</sup>
- [10] 1x Dust of Disenchantment<sup>[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3211)</sup>
- [10] 1x Hand Haversack<sup>[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=555)</sup>
- [11] 1x Sending Stones (for intra-squad communication)<sup>[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=561)</sup>
- [11] 1x Sending Stones (for communication with HQ)<sup>[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=561)</sup>
- [12] 1x Foe Stone<sup>[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3222)</sup>
- [15] 1x Flying Hook<sup>[[DDI]](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3221)</sup>

What other items (wonderous and otherwise) up to level 15 would be a good addition to the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every recon team needs an `Exodus Knife`<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3218)</sup> (*Adventurer's Vault* p171, Level 12, 13,000gp).

Basically a daily use *Rope Trick*<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/ritual.aspx?id=176)</sup> item, it gives them an extra dimensional space hideout with an invisible entrance for up to 8 hours.

They could pile in when the `Chime`<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3198)</sup> goes off. Or set it up in the middle of an open space their target would travel and execute ambushes from it.

Comment: very nice find and indeed a very handy item to have. :)

Comment: @F.Randall: Thanks for the links. I don't have a DDI subscription. `:)`

Comment: You're welcome. That DDI sub is very useful and I'm glad to share the links.